# Spring unit testing @ContextConfiguration

Tags: exception, junit, spring-batch

I am using `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to load my application context in a unit test for a spring batch application.
The application context specifies a bean with properties and their values. The values are read from a property file. So the syntax used for the values is `${a.b:default}`.
On running the junit, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'xyz'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${a.b:50}"
```

The batch job itself runs fine. I only see this issue in the junit.

Comment: does your test use the same Spring Bean configuration as your working batch? looks like the propertyplaceholderconfigurer does not work or is not there